# Plotting a horizontal parabola using Plot[ ] with one function

Tags: plotting

I understand plotting a horizontal parabola using this:

```
Plot[{Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[x]},{x, -10, 10}]
```

but I don't understand how to plot the same curve using $x=y^2$. Maybe this is because it is not a function and therefore can't be defined?

Comment: Take a look at `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Also possible: `ContourPlot[x == y^2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: @Yves and @ Kuba : thanks

Comment: Fabrizio: enjoy :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{t^2, t}, {t, -3, 3}]
```

[image]